# ViewData não está exibindo mensagem

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, html5, visual-studio-2012

Estou tentando enviar uma mensagem do Controller para View, utilizando ViewData, porém não está exibindo a mensagem.

Quando eu clico no botão "Verificar" da View é para chamar o método `Verificar()` do Controller, está chamando corretamente, e retorna a mensagem da ViewData.

Debugei o código e está aparecendo o seguinte erro na ViewData:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Controller

```
public ActionResult Verificar()
    {
        string Feedback = string.Empty;
        var DadosTemporarios = NDados.BuscaScanIDTemporaria();
        var DadosVulnExistentes = NDados.BuscaScanIDVulnExistentes();

        if (DadosTemporarios.ScanID == DadosVulnExistentes.ScanID)
        {
            Feedback = "ScanID Iguais!";
        }
        else
        {
            Feedback = "ScanID Diferentes!";
        }

        ViewData["Feedback"] = Feedback;
        return View("Index", ViewData["Feedback"]);
    }
```

View

```
<script>

function VerificaDados() {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/UploadDados/Verificar',
        type: "GET"
    });
};
</script>

<div class="container">

    <h3><strong>Importar Tabela de Vulnerabilidades</strong></h3>
    <hr />

    @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "UploadDados", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
    {
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="anexo">Anexar Arquivo CSV</label>
            <input type="file" id="FileUpload" name="FileUpload" />
        </div>
        <p>@Html.Encode(ViewData["Feedback"])</p>
        <p>
            <button class="btn btn btn-warning" type="submit" onclick="submitForm()">Upload</button>
            <button class="btn btn btn-warning" type="button" onclick="VerificaDados()">Verificar</button>
        </p>
    }

</div>
```

Comment: Você vai mostrar a mensagem da ViewData somente quando clicar no botão verificar ?

Comment: Depois que chamar o método Verificar e retornar para a Index.

Answer (score 1):

Porque utilizar o Html.Encode ?

Utilize o @ViewData["Feedback"]

Comment: Aconteceu a mesma coisa Kevin.

Comment: O Html.Encode converte um valor específico do objeto em string no HTML.

Answer (score 1):

Tente usar ela direto:

```
@ViewData["Feedback"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Tente desta maneira:

```
<p> <%: ViewData["FeedBack"] %> </p>
```

senão desta maneira:

```
<p> <%= ViewData["FeedBack"] %> </p>
```

Comment: Não deu certo, Thiago.

Comment: estranho, tente alterar para post o ajax e colocar em cima do método da controller o [HttpPost]

Comment: Já tentei fazer isso e não deu certo.